# size of images/label on libgdx skin

Tags: android, mobile, libgdx, skin

I've created a libgdx Skin using skin-composer. The problem is the all images buttons, font size are huge. How can I handle the sizes? Should I reduce the images' sizes or there are other ways?
I tried to use button.setSize(x, y) but it doesn't work :|

Answer (score 0):

According to libgdx wiki

> UI widgets do not set their own size and position. Instead, the parent
>   widget sets the size and position of each child. Widgets provide a
>   minimum, preferred, and maximum size that the parent can use as hints.
>   Some parent widgets, such as Table, can be given constraints on how to
>   size and position the children. To give a widget a specific size in a
>   layout, the widget's minimum, preferred, and maximum size are left
>   alone and size constraints are set in the parent.

so add your button to a table and set size of cell of that table.

like

```
table.add(button).width(600).height(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be attempting to size or position a widget inside a table.The table sizes and positions its children using their **preferred, minimum, or maximum size**, so the table will overwrite any size or position set previously. For example like this:

```
table.add(button).width(100).height(100);
```

Don't do that instead, you have to use preferred sizes. The table will size its widget or actor base from your preferred size. So, for example, you want to set the width and height you have to do it like this.

```
 table.add(button).minSize(minWidth, minHeight).prefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight).row()
```